# Should I use PHP's filter_input to check the existance of Post Variables?

Tags: php, filter-input

I have just started using netbeans to code PHP, and notice I am getting several code warnings stating that I should not be using superglobals such as $_POST. Instead I should be using filters.

I have done some research on `filter_input` and pretty much understand it, but have a question regarding one particular implimentation - checking the existance of a variable.

If my code currently looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

I know I can instead use:

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'name')) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

But what if I want to simply check for the existance of any POST variables. i.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    .. do something ...
}
```

Using the code below seems to work, but i don't want to go ahead and use it without understanding what this is doing, or if it is even correct.

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST)) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

Can anyone give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Calling `isset` on `$_POST` seems rather silly, as `$_POST` should _always_ be set. If anything, you'd want to do `count($_POST)` and ensure that you get a value greater than zero.

Comment: $_POST will only be set if a post header is seNt in the request. What if I have a page with a form, and submitting the form loads the same page. On the first load, no $_POST will be set. It would be reasonable to check if the form had been submitted with if(isset($_POST))

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to be late, but I was looking fot the same response. I found that we can use [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input-array.php), where the definition can be a filter constant such as FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, because all $_POST elements are strings.

```
if (filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

And I have tested also your proposed code

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST)) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

and filter_input(INPUT_POST) always retun NULL and a Warning is displayed, because filter_input expects at least two parameters.